# How to encode files using ID3v2.3?

Tags: metadata, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, id3

I am trying to get files ready for Http Live Streaming. I am then trying to embed ID3 metadata into the ts streams so a jwplayer plugin can read the timed metadata.

However, I am pretty sure the plugin only reads id3v2.3 and not id3v2.4 which id3taggenerator creates.

Does anyone know how I can either convert the tags to the older version, or create ones from that and then insert them into the files?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of one of the files you are using currently?

Comment: Well what I am doing is taking a mp4 file and splitting it into .ts segments. I basically follow these steps:

`id3taggenerator -o <output file> -artist <some artist> -url <some url>`

Then create a meta.txt file. Then segment the stream:

`mediafilesegmenter -f video -M meta.txt video.mp4`.

However, this inserts id3v2.4. I want id3v2.3.

Comment: What are you using to segment it?

Comment: Apples HLS tools: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: Ok, will have to figure out here.

Comment: JW Player does not support ID3 yet, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Ethan. Ya. Do you have any idea when it might? Or if there are alternative players that do? However, I found this plugin for jwplayer that seems to work: http://www.yospace.com/index.php/hls-sdk-for-flash-overview.html. It is able to detect where the timed id3 metadata is, it just does not seem to be passing the values of that data right now.

Comment: I don't know when we are going to add it, but I know we are looking into it. Interesting, that plugin is interesting.